# Cant open and select from dropbox(Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated)

Tags: python, selenium, select, drop-down-menu

```
fund = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//select[@id='funds_multi']")
    select_kern = Select(fund)
    select_kern.select_by_index(1)
```

I have a problem with the Select I cant select from drop box
when I am tried to open and select I got Error that said "Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated."

and I thought that maybe its happen because I didn't open the box before
so i tried to click on her but when I click i get the Error
element not interactable

[image: this is the code form the web]

Comment: Post the URL to have a look

Comment: https://pensyanet.cma.gov.il/Parameters/Index